IPTables Nat Confusion
I'm trying to make a NAT using IP Tables with the following configuration. OrangePI1 has two interfaces LAN and WAN.
LAN is a static address network where OrangePi2 lives and has a static ip.
On the WAN side is where my laptop is on a DHCP network.
Laptop (DHCP Address) <-> OrangePi1 (DHCP Address) <-> OrangePi1 (Static Address) <-> OrangepPi2 (Static Address)
The NAT is on Orangepi1 and I'd like to forward port 50001 on the DHCP side of OrangePi1 to port 50000 on the LAN with OrangePi2 on it. The DHCP network is 192.168.xxx.xxx and the static network is 10.10.10.xxx. Here's my current config script:
# External / public interface
IF_EXTERNAL="end1"
# Internal / private interface
IF_INTERNAL="end0"
# Clear existing NAT table configuration
iptables -t nat --flush

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $IF_INTERNAL -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i $IF_EXTERNAL -o $IF_INTERNAL -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $IF_INTERNAL -o $IF_EXTERNAL -j ACCEPT

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -i $IF_EXTERNAL --dport 50001 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.101:50000

# Enable forwarding in kernel IP stack
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

This configuration seems to be working but I'm confused about why masquerading the internal interface works. It seems like I should be masquerading the external interface. I also can't see the outside network when I'm in a terminal on OrangePi2 but I'm hoping I can configure this such that the OrangePi2 can have all traffic forwarded outward but the OrangePi1 only allows traffic inward on port 50001.

Assuming OrangePi1 (Static Address) is the default gateway on OrangePi2.

It seems like I should be masquerading the external interface

You would need to do that if OrangePi2 needs to initiate communication. For example, if you need to web browse or perform a system update on it.

why masquerading the internal interface

You shouldn't need it given the assumption, but if the fact is you don't have a default route configured on OrangePi2, the masquerading would make the DNAT'd traffics "look" originated from OrangePi1 (Static Address), which eliminates the need of a default route for the case.

I also can't see the outside network when I'm in a terminal on OrangePi2

Sounds like my assumption is not the fact.

iptables -A FORWARD -i $IF_EXTERNAL -o $IF_INTERNAL -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $IF_INTERNAL -o $IF_EXTERNAL -j ACCEPT

Note that these rules are not sufficient to allow the DNAT'd traffics. You'd also need something like:
iptables -A FORWARD -i $IF_EXTERNAL -o $IF_INTERNAL -d 10.10.10.101 -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT

The fact that you don't need such rule indicates that you are NOT actually filtering in the FORWARD chain, i.e., the chain policy is ACCEPT and there is no "fallback" DROP or REJECT rule. (If you don't actually need / want to filter in FORWARD, you don't need to add any rules to it. Just keep the chain policy ACCEPT.)

You're correct my default gateway is the DHCP network.
default via 192.168.10.1 dev end0 proto dhcp src 192.168.10.158 metric 101

And my iptables rules are:
`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.10.10.101         tcp dpt:5000
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

@soccermom420 I was talking about the default gateway on OrangePi2. Please don't add output dumps as comment but to your post by editing it. Also, use iptables-save instead. The thing is, what did you want to express / convey with the comments anyway?

I apologize for the bad formatting. The default route of OrangePi2 is the static address of OrangePi1. I'm a bit confused because even after adding the new forwarding rule it doesn't seem to work. But I would like to install packages on OrangePi2.

@soccermom420 I think I've covered everything in my answer.

Could you possibly reword your answer? It's a bit confusing to me.
